# How to recognize and differentiate between single, double, and triple clicks in Arduino?

Tags: arduino

I'm trying to make a sketch for Arduino that differentiates between single, double, triple, maybe quadruple clicks, and hold clicks with a push button.

I've tried making my own program that uses a variable that increments with each click but haven't had much success. I then found this Arduino sketch that mostly does what I need, but lacks triple and quadruple clicks.

https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=14479.0

I just know I need to copy the same logic the double click uses but haven't figured it out.

```
/* 4-Way Button:  Click, Double-Click, Press+Hold, and Press+Long-Hold Test Sketch

By Jeff Saltzman
Oct. 13, 2009

To keep a physical interface as simple as possible, this sketch demonstrates generating four output events from a single push-button.
1) Click:  rapid press and release
2) Double-Click:  two clicks in quick succession
3) Press and Hold:  holding the button down
4) Long Press and Hold:  holding the button for a long time
*/

#define buttonPin 19        // analog input pin to use as a digital input
#define ledPin1 17          // digital output pin for LED 1
#define ledPin2 16          // digital output pin for LED 2
#define ledPin3 15          // digital output pin for LED 3
#define ledPin4 14          // digital output pin for LED 4

// LED variables
boolean ledVal1 = false;    // state of LED 1
boolean ledVal2 = false;    // state of LED 2
boolean ledVal3 = false;    // state of LED 3
boolean ledVal4 = false;    // state of LED 4

//=================================================

void setup() {
   // Set button input pin
   pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);
   digitalWrite(buttonPin, HIGH );
   // Set LED output pins
   pinMode(ledPin1, OUTPUT);
   digitalWrite(ledPin1, ledVal1);
   pinMode(ledPin2, OUTPUT);
   digitalWrite(ledPin2, ledVal2);
   pinMode(ledPin3, OUTPUT);    
   digitalWrite(ledPin3, ledVal3);
   pinMode(ledPin4, OUTPUT);    
   digitalWrite(ledPin4, ledVal4);
}

void loop() {
   // Get button event and act accordingly
   int b = checkButton();
   if (b == 1) clickEvent();
   if (b == 2) doubleClickEvent();
   if (b == 3) holdEvent();
   if (b == 4) longHoldEvent();
}

//=================================================
// Events to trigger

void clickEvent() {
   ledVal1 = !ledVal1;
   digitalWrite(ledPin1, ledVal1);
}
void doubleClickEvent() {
   ledVal2 = !ledVal2;
   digitalWrite(ledPin2, ledVal2);
}
void holdEvent() {
   ledVal3 = !ledVal3;
   digitalWrite(ledPin3, ledVal3);
}
void longHoldEvent() {
   ledVal4 = !ledVal4;
   digitalWrite(ledPin4, ledVal4);
}

//=================================================
//  MULTI-CLICK:  One Button, Multiple Events

// Button timing variables
int debounce = 20;          // ms debounce period to prevent flickering when pressing or releasing the button
int DCgap = 250;            // max ms between clicks for a double click event
int holdTime = 1000;        // ms hold period: how long to wait for press+hold event
int longHoldTime = 3000;    // ms long hold period: how long to wait for press+hold event

// Button variables
boolean buttonVal = HIGH;   // value read from button
boolean buttonLast = HIGH;  // buffered value of the button's previous state
boolean DCwaiting = false;  // whether we're waiting for a double click (down)
boolean DConUp = false;     // whether to register a double click on next release, or whether to wait and click
boolean singleOK = true;    // whether it's OK to do a single click
long downTime = -1;         // time the button was pressed down
long upTime = -1;           // time the button was released
boolean ignoreUp = false;   // whether to ignore the button release because the click+hold was triggered
boolean waitForUp = false;        // when held, whether to wait for the up event
boolean holdEventPast = false;    // whether or not the hold event happened already
boolean longHoldEventPast = false;// whether or not the long hold event happened already

int checkButton() {    
   int event = 0;
   buttonVal = digitalRead(buttonPin);
   // Button pressed down
   if (buttonVal == LOW && buttonLast == HIGH && (millis() - upTime) > debounce)
   {
       downTime = millis();
       ignoreUp = false;
       waitForUp = false;
       singleOK = true;
       holdEventPast = false;
       longHoldEventPast = false;
       if ((millis()-upTime) < DCgap && DConUp == false && DCwaiting == true)  DConUp = true;
       else  DConUp = false;
       DCwaiting = false;
   }
   // Button released
   else if (buttonVal == HIGH && buttonLast == LOW && (millis() - downTime) > debounce)
   {        
       if (not ignoreUp)
       {
           upTime = millis();
           if (DConUp == false) DCwaiting = true;
           else
           {
               event = 2;
               DConUp = false;
               DCwaiting = false;
               singleOK = false;
           }
       }
   }
   // Test for normal click event: DCgap expired
   if ( buttonVal == HIGH && (millis()-upTime) >= DCgap && DCwaiting == true && DConUp == false && singleOK == true && event != 2)
   {
       event = 1;
       DCwaiting = false;
   }
   // Test for hold
   if (buttonVal == LOW && (millis() - downTime) >= holdTime) {
       // Trigger "normal" hold
       if (not holdEventPast)
       {
           event = 3;
           waitForUp = true;
           ignoreUp = true;
           DConUp = false;
           DCwaiting = false;
           //downTime = millis();
           holdEventPast = true;
       }
       // Trigger "long" hold
       if ((millis() - downTime) >= longHoldTime)
       {
           if (not longHoldEventPast)
           {
               event = 4;
               longHoldEventPast = true;
           }
       }
   }
   buttonLast = buttonVal;
   return event;
}
```

If you want background, this is for a device for someone to navigate Windows who can only use one button and a joystick, and this is what my current idea requires, but I'm not a programmer so having a bit of a rough time.

Comment: As long as you have good debouncing, you can just count the time in a window

Comment: use the Bounce2 library